# Which is the correct way to restart Solr

Tags: linux, solr

I have made some changes at Solr Schema file and I see I 'am forced to restart SolR in order to have Solr running with new schema updates.

This is hosted on a server where solr is running from a start.jar file but I'am not sure how it was started(maybe with nohup)

I have found a way to stop SolR from another question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically):

```
kill `ps uax | grep -i "java -jar start.jar" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

After this, I start SolR with "java -jar start.jar".

Is this a correct way to do the restart or is there built-in/better way to restart the jar?

Answer (score 4):

At [Websolr](http://websolr.com/), we use a combination of a custom `init.d` script plus [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to start Solr and ensure that it stays running.

That said, for a simpler self-hosted setup, I would recommend using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to start and stop Solr, if your system has Upstart available. Upstart scripts have the benefit of being fairly simple, and Upstart does a good job restarting processes in the event they crash. Plus the start and stop commands (`start` and `stop`, respectively) are pretty easy to remember for the next time you need to make Solr aware of new configs.

Here is a good blog post covering [starting Solr with Upstart](http://anthonyw.net/2011/03/using-solr-with-upstart-instead-of-init-d/). I've copied their upstart script below; be sure to update the relevant paths to match your system:

```
description "Solr Search Server"

# Make sure the file system and network devices have started before
# we begin the daemon
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)

# Stop the event daemon on system shutdown
stop on shutdown

# Respawn the process on unexpected termination
respawn

# The meat and potatoes
exec /usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Dsolr.solr.home=/path/to/solr/home -Djetty.home=/path/to/jetty -jar /path/to/jetty/start.jar >> /var/log/solr.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this approach http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD.

Using a command like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0
```

will just reload all your configuration files and you will not have problems in doing SOLR queries querying while the core is restarted.

Comment: This doesn't work in a standard installation. Probably I need to enable SolR multicore features to be able to use this kind of reload.

Comment: It worked for me:
My solr.xml cores configuration looks like this:
   
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
        <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
    </cores>

I used this link to reload core:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=collection1

Comment: Using the included Jetty (start.jar) seems a kludge. Consider setting it up in Tomcat in a multicore configuratiob. I included instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188816/how-to-start-and-stop-solr-from-a-user-created-windows-service/7203038#7203038

Answer (score 1):

For SolrCloud, from the solr folder run:

```
bin/solr restart -e cloud -noprompt
```

Comment: When you execute this command, by default it does not use the system wide configuration located in `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` but uses the `solr.in.sh` script located next to the `bin/solr` script.  Do not do this unless you specify the same global configuration to use like the default service does by specifying the environment variable:  `SOLR_INCLUDE="/etc/default/solr.in.sh"`